# setting the ContextPath in Jetty running under ServiceMix (OSGI)

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, apache-karaf, apache-felix, apache-servicemix

Here is my brief background of environment.

I am trying to convert a myapp WAR to an OSGi compliant by making the MANIFEST.MF as shown below, and wanted to deploy this war in ServiceMix an OSGi based container.

## MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 2.0
Bundle-SymbolicName: myapp
Bundle-Version: 2.1.dev
Bundle-Name: Jetty.myapp
Bundle-Vendor: ABC
Created-By: 1.6.0_25-b06 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Bundle-ClassPath: .,WEB-INF/lib, WEB-INF/classes, xforms/xsltforms
Web-ContextPath: myapp
Webapp-Context: myapp
Import-Package: javax.servlet
Built-By: root
Project-Name: ABC_PRJ
Project-Version: 2.1.dev
Project-Build: ${DSTAMP}
SVN-Revision: ${svn.revision}
```

The ContextPath is getting set to null, where should I set the contextPath and how? You may observe the 'null' string in the FileNotFound Exception.

log:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: null/WEB-INF/myForms-config.xml (No such file or
        directory)
```

## My web.xml in myapp is :

```
<contextPath>/</contextPath>
<context-param>
      <param-name>myForms.configfile</param-name>
      <param-value>WEB-INF/myForms-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Is it the problem with myapp or jetty or serviceMix? Any Clue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the web-contextpath via the Manifest and not via the web.xml
for more information take a look at [Pax-Web](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxweb/Pax+Web)